# Getting The Configurable Front End Product To Display The Cheapest Simple Product Price As A 'From' Price

Tags: configurable-product, price, simple-product

I am having an issue where my configurable product, which is not actually a product that is for sale, is displaying a price of zero on the frontend website. I would like this frontend product to display the cheapest variant in it's simple products as a 'From' price.

The only way I can currently see how to do this is to have the configurable sku priced as the cheapest, and then the more expensive skus are priced with the difference between the cheapest and their actually price. This is because when I go to select the variant I want within a configurable sku, it says '$0 + $12.99'. $12.99 is the price of a t-shirt and this is the cheapest variant, so I'd like the sku to say $12.99 and then just change to the price of whatever variant/simple product is selected, not ADD on the price to the configurable.

Any help is welcome, this is really frustrating.

Thanks, Dan.

Comment: in the associated products you should be able to set a standard price

Answer (score 0):

@Thomas is correct - you just need to set the products to have 'the standard price'.

If you have a lot of products to update then you might want to put together a simple script that iterates through the configurable products, loading their simple products, finding the lowest price and updating the configurable accordingly.

Another method to achieve this is with a spreadsheet import/export.

There are many, many factors that influence the price of a product in Magento. Technically the lowest price simple product might not be the 'lowest price'. There are size price options, sales rules and plenty else to affect price. However, you need a simple update and not to worry.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a go and report back. Great help guys.

Comment: With this do you mean the '_super_attribute_price_corr'? I have prices in for each type ie T-shirt = 9.99, hoodie = 15.99 but the configurable is still appearing on the front end with a price of 0.

Each simple product has it's own price, some are different, but they never display OR change when selcting the dropdowns on the front end. The price always displays as 0.

Comment: Any javascript errors on the page?

Comment: None that I can see. I've outsourced some help via Odesk so hopefully they can look into it. Thanks for your help @Woolfie

Answer (score 0):

If the question is for Magento 2, there is known issue: https://github.com/magento/inventory/pull/2200